# Replacing constructor with Hooks in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, react-hooks

I am trying to implement an modal example inside a class within a function. The class based example looks like this:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };
}

export default Dashboard
```

I am specifically trying to replace the constructor with hooks that will work inside my function based component. As I am new to React, this is somewhat confusing. Here's what I have so far; is this correct?

```
export const Table = () => {
   const[showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
   const[hideModal, setHideModal] = useState(true);

  showModal = () => {
    setShowModal({ show: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    setHideModal({ show: false });
  };

  ...
 
  return (
    ...
    <button type="button" onClick={showModal}>
    ...
   )
}
```

Something seems off here. Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: You only need one state to show or hide the modal (true or false). Also just write ` setShowModal(true)`. This state isn't part of an object like it is in the class component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it to false/true, don't create an object with `show: false/true`

```
export const Table = () => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(true);
  };

  const hideModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  ...
 
  return (
    ...
    <button type="button" onClick={showModal}>
    ...
   )
}
```